# MySQL overhead - how to tune up server to speed up bad queries

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, percona

I have a shop on PHP platform (bad developed) where there are a lot of bad queries (long queries without indexes, order by rand(), dynamic counting, ..)

I do not have the possibility to change the queries for now, but I have to tune the server to stay alive.

I tried everything I know, I had very big databases, which I optimized with changing MySQL engine and tune it, but it is first project, where everything goes down.

Current situation:

**1. Frontend (PHP)** - AWS m4.large instance, Amazon Linux (latest), PHP 7.0 with opcache enabled (apache module), mod_pagespeed enabled with external Memcached on AWS Elasticache (t2.micro, 5% average load)

**2. SQL** - Percona DB with TokuDB engine on AWS c4.xlarge instance (50% average load)

I need to lower the instances, mainly the c4.xlarge, but if I switch down to c4.large, after a few hours there is a big overload.

Database has only 300MB of data, I tried query cache, InnoDB, XtraDB, ... with no success, and the traffic is also very low. PHP uses MySQLi extension.

Do you know any possible solution, how to lower the load without refactoring the queries?

Comment: Ugly job but has to be done... refactor those queries.. If it was done correctly the first time round then you wouldn't have this problem :P

Comment: You can index your queries. Just turn on the slow query log for a little bit, then try to figure out which queries can be indexed. Use Percona's toolkit for some of that. You can also check over on https://dba.stackexchange.com for more options.

Comment: You can install a tool like NewRelic and get the most used queries. Then you can focus on refactor the relevant ones.

Comment: Thanks for answers, the problem is, that I cannot refactor queries, because I cannot modify the system. So I am looking for some tweak at the side of the SQL. E.g. if I had problems with overhead, I used query_cache, raise some variables, change the engine, ... 

I did everything I knew, so I am looking for something I do not know, as e.g. to change some TokuDB variable (I have enough RAM, but I want to lower processor load).

Comment: Maybe someting is possible at side of PHP, but opcache is installed, I monitor it and has enought memory to run.

Answer (score 0):

Use of www.mysqlcalculator.com would be a quick way to get a brain check on about a dozen memory consumption factors in less than 2 minutes.
Would love to see your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES, if you could get them posted to allow analysis of activity and configuration requests.  3 minutes of your GENERAL_LOG during a busy time would be interesting and could identify troublesome/time consuming SELECT's, etc.

Comment: @LordMagik     If you are ready to make your system faster, please post to pastebin.com and share the links A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours of UPTIME and B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; for helpful suggestions to improve response time.  Yes, I realize this request is 2 years old, still here, ready to assist.